# ARM64 label of Azure Devops hosted agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-hosted-agent

In the [Sprint 171 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-171-update#additional-agent-platform-arm64) of Azure DevOps, Microsoft announced to support Linux/ARM64 hosted agents. To be able to use that as Microsoft hosted agent, I need to know the correct label for such an image. I can not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution now.
If you install the QEMU package on the hosted agent, this can emulate any ARM device and arm applications can be executed. At least for the usage of docker, that works well.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could mark it as an answer, In this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Thanks.

Comment: This runs in a fully emulated environment. It may work for your usage, but it does incur a large performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

We can add the task Bash and enter the script `printenv` to list all env variable, then check the variable `AGENT_OSARCHITECTURE`, as the test result, all ubuntu hosted agent architectures are x64 instead of ARM64, you can raise this issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21), the Azure DevOps product team will check it and give you a detailed explanation..

As a workaround, we can install [Linux ARM64 self-hosted agent](https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.175.1/vsts-agent-linux-arm64-2.175.1.tar.gz), you can refer to this [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

That release announcement is pretty brief.  I didn't necessarily take is as hosted agents would be supported, just that you could self-host the agent if you wanted.

If you want to find the details of what is supported and available on the latest images, that is all captured on the GitHub page for virtual Environments.  Specifically, you can find the [YAML label](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments#available-environments).

As-of 2020-09, I don't see anything referencing ARM64 available.

`ubuntu-20.04`, `ubuntu-latest` or `ubuntu-18.04`, `ubuntu-16.04`, `macos-latest` or `macos-10.15`, `windows-latest` or `windows-2019`, `windows-2016`

Comment: I hoped, that they forgot to update. You think, they meant you can use only self hosted agents with Arm64? They announced, that Azure Pipelines now support Linux/Arm64. Why should they mention the OS, if they do not host themselves?

Comment: Yeah, my interpretation was that it was self-hosted only.  Based on the comments, sounds like it was a highly requested community item.  I agree adding the wording that it is available for self-hosting would have been more clear.